# Collision resistance of a function which chooses the hash from a large table of hashes

Tags: cryptanalysis, collision-resistance

Let's say you know a (possibly) large table of ids and some corresponsing hashes $h_{ID_j} = H(ID_j | secret_j)$. The resulting table looks like 
$$ ID_1 | h_{ID_1} $$
$$ ID_2 | h_{ID_2} $$
$$ ... $$
$$ ID_n | h_{ID_n} $$

The hashes of the ids are secretly created by n id owners with each knowing a randomly generated secret $secret_j$. No owner inputted more than one entry.

Now I want to have a look on the the public boolean circuit functions
$$f_1(ID|secret) := H(ID|secret) = h_{ID_1} \lor H(ID|secret) = h_{ID_2} \lor ... \lor H(ID|secret) = h_{ID_n}$$
or
$$f_2(ID|secret) := H(ID|secret) = h_{ID_{r_1}} \lor H(ID|secret) = h_{ID_{r_2}} \lor ... \lor H(ID|secret) = h_{ID_{r_t}} \lor H(ID|secret) = h_{ID_s} \lor H(ID|secret) = h_{ID_{r_{t+1}}} \lor H(ID|secret) = h_{ID_{r_{t+2}}} \lor ... \lor H(ID|secret) = h_{ID_{r_u}}$$ with random chosen $t, r_q, q < n, u < n$ and $f_2, s, u$ being fixed chosen and published.
My questions now are

1. if $f_1$ is collision resistant (finding two ID|secret and ID'|secret' such that $f_1$ outputs 1) if H is a random oracle.
2. if $f_1$ is collision resistant (finding two ID|secret and ID'|secret' such that $f_1$ outputs 1) if H is only a collision resistant function.
3. if there a way to define the random values $t, r_q$ such that they reveal as less about the ID of the proof as possible. Which formal security model can apply there?
4. if there exisits a secure function which outputs 1 if $f_1$ or $f_2$ outputs 1 and the chance that function outputs 1 if $f_1$ or $f_2$ outputs 0 is negligible and is faster to describe in boolean circuits than $f_1$ or $f_2$.

Comment: is $|$ concatenation?

Comment: yes, | is concatenation